Can someone explain this Dutch 5 headed monster engraving?
I stumbled upon this image (below) on Wikipedia and was curious at to its meaning.

The description links to 2 other Wikipedia articles, but I feel like I am lacking context on Christian history to really understand those articles. I did a reverse image search, but didn't find any website that explained its meaning well. It is easy enough to translate the Latin in the engraving with Google, but that doesn't answer all the question.
Clearly there is a lot of very strong symbolism being invoked. Some of it is obvious, such a baby, branch, and sword labeled "Innocent", "Peace", and "Justice" being trampled upon. Much of it involving the monster itself is not. If there is someone knowledgeable about 17th century Dutch culture, could you please offer some explanation. Thank you?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Mythology&Folklore! I added the image itself from Wikimedia into the body of your Question. I don't know why the Community Bot seems to have an issue with how your Question is written; I think it's plenty clear.

Thanks for adding the picture. I wasn't sure how to do that.

No problem: you're welcome :)

This is a version of a 17th-century Dutch satirical print known as De Warminiaen, where “Warminiaen” is a portmanteau of “war” (confusion, mess) and “Arminiaen” (Arminian), a follower of Jacobus Arminius, the Dutch religious reformer. In Frederik Muller’s catalog of Dutch prints, this is number 1355:

1355 De Warminiaen, — Vinnige spotprent op de Arminianen. — Een monster op 2 beenen en 2 duivelspooten, met 5 hoofden: (Fraus—Seditio–Opinio–Stupiditas–Avaritia) en een deksel der boosheid: (Velamen nequitide) vertreedt een kind Innocentia; op zijne borst stant: Warminiaen. Met vele Lat. en in h. Hollandsch vertaalde inscriptiën; en bovenaan: „De nieuwsgierige hoop, ’t Veelhoofdich Wonderdier, Verliest na al syn cracht, door Godes recht bestier.” Regts: 1618 exc. Znd. nm. v. grav. Hg. 23½, br. 15½ dm. fol. Zeldzaam. Dezelfde plaat, vroegere druk, zonder inschrift: Warminiaen, zonder de Holl. vertalingen der Lat. inschriften, en vele Holl. verzen, en zonder jaar. V. ond. 2 gegrav. Lat. versregels: „Obfirmatus ubi studia in contraria menteis, Error agit monstrum hoc exitiale parit.” — Veel zeldzamer dan de voorg. — Kan dit ook eene oudere plaat zijo, bij eene andere gelegenheid gemaakt en nu door als hierboven bijroegingen als hierboven vermeld, op dit jaar gepast? - Bij Brandt, Reform. II. 935 wordt de plaat: de Warminiaen, als een der vinnigste aangehaald.
1355 The Warminian — savage caricature on the Arminians — A monster on two legs and two devil’s feet, with five heads (Fraud, Sedition, Opinion, Stupidity, and Greed) and a veil of iniquity tramples a child Innocence; on his chest is Warminian. With many Latin inscriptions translated into high Dutch; and at the top: “The curious heap, the many-headed wonder beast, loses after all its power, through God’s rightful command.” Right: 1618 example. Without name of engraver. Height 23½, width 15½ cm folio. Rare. The same plate, earlier edition, without the Warminian inscription, without the Dutch translations of the Latin inscriptions, and many Dutch lines, and without year, and two engraved Latin lines of verse: “Where zeal is stubborn in contrary minds, Error gives birth to this fatal monster.” — Much rarer than the aforementioned. — Could this also be an older print, made on another occasion and now, by the additions mentioned above, appropriate to this year? — Brandt, in History of the Reformation, volume 2, page 935, says that the print, The Warminian, is one of the most savage.
Frederik Muller (1870). De Nederlandsche geschiedenis in platen, page 172. Amsterdam: Frederik Muller.

The picture in the question does not match Muller’s description exactly, for example, none of the heads are labelled “Fraud” or “Stupidity”, and one of the heads is labelled ἈθεόΤΗS (godlessness). However, it is clear from Muller’s catalog that there were multiple versions of the print, and it is notable that ἈθεόΤΗS is a different hand than the other captions, suggesting a later alteration.
This is the referenced passage in Brandt:

Men maekte ook meenigte van schempprinten tot hunner smaedt, met naemen de print van den Arminiaenschen Drekwagen; het Arminiaensch Testament; en de rechtvaerdige Sift: spottende met de Remonsranten, met de voorige regeering, met het afdanken der Waerdtgelders, met het veranderen der Magistraeten, en voorts alles verbeeldende wat tot spijt of verwijt kon strekken. Daer toe diende ook de print van seker beeldt, de Warminiaen genaemt, te defer tijdt gedrukt, een Monster hebbende vijf hoofden daer men het Bedrogh het Oproer, het Misverstandt, de Domheit, en de Gierigheit door socht te verbeelden. Doch gelijk dese dingen de verbittering onder ’t gemeene volk seer deeden aengroeijen, soo wierden se, als aenhitsingen der twist, van alle redelijke en destige mannen versoeit.
Great numbers too of satirical Prints and Cuts† were made in reproach to them; such as for instance, that called The Arminian Dung-Cart; The Arminian Last Will; and the Sieve of Justice: all of them ridiculing and exposing the Remonstrants,‡ the past Administration, the discharging the Warders, the change of the Magistrates, and, in a word, representing every incident with the utmost spite and rancour. Of this sort too was a Picture, which they called the Warminian, representing a Monster with five heads, which were to denote Fraud, Sedition, Misunderstanding, Madness and Avarice.§ But these things, as they greatly increased the heats and animosities among the common people, by adding fuel to the fire of contention, were detested by all good and reasonable men.
Gerard Brandt (1674). Historie der Reformatie, volume 2, pages 935–936. Amsterdam: Jan Rieuwertsz. Translated by John Chamberlayne (1721). The History of the Reformation, volume 2, page 567. London: T. Wood. Spelling modernized.
† “cut, n. an engraving, woodcut, linocut, etc.” (OED) ‡ Followers of Arminius, named for the “Remonstrances” they made against Calvinism. § Note that these captions for the heads are different from the ones given by Muller, indicating the plurality of versions.

The monster’s five heads correspond in number to the Five Articles of Remonstrance advanced by the followers of Arminius, which were five points where they disagreed with Calvinists.
Here’s a 1618 version of the print at the Rijksmuseum in Amsterdam (object number RP-P-OB-77.293). This corresponds exactly to the description in Muller, and the label ‘Warminiaen’ on the monster’s chest confirms the satirical target.


This is an excellent answer! Thank you for finding the additional information. Having the print with the target labelled Warminiaen definitely confirms the target. It still isn't clear to me how the heads are supposed to correspond to the articles of remonstrance (other than in number), but now that the target is confirmed, the descriptions saying that they are supposed to correspond also seem reliable

I think the correspondence is just in number: if there were a detailed scheme where Opinion represented Conditional Election and so on, then there would have needed to be captions explaining it.

Following the link from the Wikimedia page (which itself gives the description "Polemical allegory of Arminianism as a five-headed monster, based on the Five Articles of Remonstrance of 1610.") to the source here, there is a description in Dutch, which translates to the following (per DeepL):

Allegorical five-headed and four-legged monster. This monstrosity has the heads of Avarice (Avaritia), the masked Deceit (Fraus), Riot (Seditio) and Delusion (Opinio). The pig's head is marked with a Greek term (Stupidity / Stupiditas?). In his hands he carries attributes of Envy (Invidia) and War (Bellum). Under his feet he tramples on Innocence (Innocentia) and Peace (Pax) and Justice (Justitia). With inscriptions and below the plate a two-line Latin caption.

The description seems odd though. The Greek term ἀθεότης atheótēs means "godlessness", not stupidity, and the label "fraus" for Deceit is missing entirely.
My own translation of the Latin caption is:

Surely(?) where studies in contrary minds make an error, this destructive monster is born.

The sash is labelled velamen neqvitiae "veil of profligacy". I'm unsure exactly how to interpret this. Likewise I am unsure how to interpret the bird's legs.
As you say, one the ground there is a baby labelled innocentia "innocence", an olive branch labelled pax "peace" and a broken sword labelled ivstitia "justice". The symbolism here seems clear that the monster is a threat to such values.
It is not clear to me where the Wikimedia page gets the information that this is attacking Arminianism, or how this is based on the Five Articles of Remonstrance (the only parallel I can see is that the monster has five heads). That description appears in the earliest version of the Wikimedia page, but has no clear source. I do not believe it to be reliable.
What "studies in contrary minds" means is also not entirely clear. I suspect it is referring to playing devil's advocate, or possibly disagreement with classical authors (as would become more common amongst philosophers during the Enlightenment a century or so after this woodcut).
It seems to me then that, discounting the information from the Wikimedia page as unreliable, this is likely an attack against certain philosophies, saying that they would lead to seven vices (envy, avarice, godlessness, deceit, riot, conjecture, and war), the number presumably deliberately echoing the seven deadly sins (which of course also include the first two vices) and that they pose a threat to innocence, peace, and justice.
Unfortunately without further information on this particular woodcut, I suspect it is not possible to be confident as to what philosophies the engraver is attacking.
